# OpenCV Python cv2.imshow() error

Tags: python, image, opencv, directory

I am starting out with OpenCV in Python, and I have the following simple code from a Youtube tutorial:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('lion.jpg')

# show the image
# cv2.imshow has 2 parameters: the first is the name of the window in which we are showing the image
# and the second is the matrix referring to the image we want to show
cv2.imshow('image', img)

# We want the program to exit when the user presses a key
cv2.waitKey(0)
# Once the user presses the key, we want the program to shut down
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:331: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

The error occurred on the line where I call cv2.imshow().

Is this because there is no such image lion.jpg already included in the cv2 module? Because I tried using a random picture from my images folder instead and it threw the same error.

Comment: You're trying to show an empty image, since you didn't check whether `imread` succeeded. This sort of question is asked here on pretty much daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur with opencv for different reason.

- The image is of zero size (which is not your case, but it might happen if you do something silly like `img = img[50:40, :]`)
- The image does not exist. In this case, make sure the path to your image is complete : `lion.jpg` should be in the folder from which you execute the python code. Otherwise you should write down the path to the image.

And to my knowledge, there is no such `lion.jpg` image included in opencv, but I may have overlooked it.